# RethinkDb query current date time between two date columns

Tags: mysql, sql, rethinkdb

Sorry if this a really a basic/noob question, but I am really new to rethinkDb coming from SQL.

**(1)**

Below is the query in SQL that I wanted to convert into ReThinkDb. This may be really simple, but I cannot make it right.

**SQL equivalent:**

```
select *  
from reservations
where
    room_id = 'b1a7ddd3-ddfd-4624-8e85-79b47fb19f99' and  
    now() between reservation_start and reservation_end
```

**RethinkDb Query (with error):**

```
r.db("myDb").table("reservations").filter(function(doc){ 
    return 
        doc("room_id").eq("b1a7ddd3-ddfd-4624-8e85-79b47fb19f99")
            .and( r.now().between(doc("reservation_start ").date(), doc("reservation_end").date()) )
    }
)
```

I just want to return the reservations scheduled today, or ongoing if it is already started but not yet finished (end date-time).

**(2)**

Reservations have a column or field for attendees which is a list/array of name/email:

```
attendees: [
  {"name": "Attendee 1", "email": "attendee1@test.com"},
  {"name": "Attendee 2", "email": "attendee2@test.com"},
  {"name": "Attendee 3", "email": "attendee3@test.com"},
]
```

I would like to add a filter to check that an `email` exists in the `list of attendees`.

It is like querying for: The email `attendee2@test.com` has a reservation today for `room 101`.

If querying with attende email is not possible or complicated... I don't mind as I can do the checking in my application. What matters is the rethinkdb query equivalent for `now() between dateColumnStart and dateColumnEnd`.

**Update: Added sample data stored in DB (RethinkDB)**

```
{
"attendees": [
    {
        "email": dummyUser101@gmail.com, »
        "name":  "Dummy User 101"
    } ,
    {
        "email": dummyUser102@gmail.com, »
        "name":  "Dummy User 102"
    }
] ,
"id":  "45qum29cel0cm4ejl2obi6pttj" ,
"room_id":  "7cc8e51d-e3fa-4d84-b7e6-9ebf8975754a" ,
"reservation_end":  "2018-11-23T02:00:00" , //10AM (GMT8)
"reservation_start":  "2018-11-19T00:00:00" , //8AM (GMT8)
"details":  "Week event 8AM-10AM Test"
}

{
"attendees": [
    {
        "email": dummyUser103@gmail.com, »
        "name":  "Dummy User 103"
    } ,
    {
        "email": dummyUser101@gmail.com, »
        "name":  "Dummy User 101"
    } ,
    {
        "email": dummyUser102@gmail.com, »
        "name":  "Dummy User 102"
    }
] ,
"id":  "6ejq8h6tvlpnjiskvt4kthfmss_20181123T060000Z" ,
"room_id":  "7cc8e51d-e3fa-4d84-b7e6-9ebf8975754a" ,
"reservation_end":  "2018-11-23T07:00:00" , //3PM (GMT8)
"reservation_start":  "2018-11-23T06:00:00" , //2PM (GMT8)
"details":  "Test Reservation"
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**(1)**

You cannot use between in the filter. Between gets you all documents between two keys. See docu here: https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/between/

What you need is the "during" keyword.

```
r.db("myDB").table("reservations").filter(function(doc){ 
    return doc("room_id").eq("b1a7ddd3-ddfd-4624-8e85-79b47fb19f99")
        .and( r.now().during(
           r.ISO8601(doc("reservation_start"),{defaultTimezone:"+08:00"}),
           r.ISO8601(doc("reservation_end"),{defaultTimezone:"+08:00"})))
    }
)
```

Comment: I tried, but I am getting error `e: ISO 8601 string has no time zone, and no default time zone was provided`

Comment: Can you send an example how your dates are stored?

Comment: ex: "2018-11-12T08:30:00"

Comment: then you have to provide a defaultTimezone argument. eg.: "Z" for UTC. See my edit

Comment: Hi @Peter, I tried and it did not return any error... but I did not get any result either. I updated the post and added a sample data from DB. I am thinking the problem is on the date format. I feel so dumb with rethinkDb :( it would be really fast to work this out if the project is in SQL.

Comment: No result is the correct result in your case :) :
r.now is "2018-11-17T07:47:13Z" which is not during either of those intervals you provided in the sample

Comment: also, i adapted my post to your timezone GMT+8

Comment: Thanks @Peter, it really helps :) now I just need to convert this to java ^_^